# A pic by pic hide and show slideshow - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, selectors-api

I am creating a slideshow with html/css/javascript. It should look like a trail of images that shows a new image as the last image shown is hovered over. But I can only get the first image to appear. The functions I wrote to continue the slideshow effect are not effective. What is missing from the functions?

```
    <div class = "line1">

        <img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash2.jpg" alt = "Another picture you can't see" onmouseover = "mover ()" onmouseout = "mout ()">

        <img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash3.jpg" alt = "You must be blind" onmouseover = "mover ()" onmouseout = "mout ()">

        <img id = "second" src = "../Pics/January_2019/screen.jpg" alt = "It's a mirror" >

    </div>

    <br></br>

    <div class = "line2">

        <img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash4.jpg" alt = "Or we're not linking up" onmouseover = "mover ()" onmouseout = "mout ()">

        <img class = "crash" src = "../Pics/January_2019/crash5.jpg" alt = "Still checkin?" onmouseover = "mover ()" onmouseout = "mout ()">

        <img id = "third" src = "../Pics/January_2019/NYbridge.jpg" alt = "A bridge you can't see">

    </div>
```

css

```
.crash {
display: none;
}

.brash {
display: inline-flex;
width: 21%;
padding: 0.75%;
margin: 0.75%;
}   

.line1, .line2 {
display: flex;
}
```

js

```
let shine = document.querySelectorAll('.crash');

const glide = document.querySelector('#first');

let count;
```

If I assign the count (=) instead of compare it (==) the first image slide pops up. Otherwise nothing shows when I hover over the first image.

```
mover = function () {

if (count == 4) {

    count = 0;
}

shine[count].classList.replace('crash', 'brash');

}   


mout = function => {setTimeout (removefunc, 200)}



removefunc = function () {

if (count >= 1) {

    shine[count].classList.replace ('brash', 'crash');
}

count+=1;
}

glide.onmouseover = mover;

glide.onmouseout = mout;

shine[0].onmouseover = mover;

shine[0].onmouseout = mout;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure in what you are trying to achieve, but it sounds like you want two 'carousels' each displaying one image at a time. And every time you hover that image, either the next image in that carousel should appear, or start at the first image again. Correct?

If so I think your code can be much shorter and less complex. Like so...

```js
document.querySelectorAll('img').forEach((img) => {
  img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    if (img.classList.contains('hold')) {
      img.classList.remove('hold')
      return false
    }
    let index = Array.from(img.parentNode.children).indexOf(img)
    let nextImg = img.parentNode.querySelectorAll('img')[index + 1]
    let firstImg = img.parentNode.querySelectorAll('img')[0]

    img.classList.remove('active')
    if (nextImg) {
      nextImg.classList.add('active', 'hold')
    } else {
      firstImg.classList.add('active', 'hold')
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.line img {
  width: 21%;
  padding: 0.75%;
  margin: 0.75%;
  display: none;
}

.line img.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <img class="active" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash2.jpg" alt="Another picture you can't see" />
  <img src="../Pics/January_2019/crash3.jpg" alt="You must be blind" />
  <img src="../Pics/January_2019/screen.jpg" alt="It's a mirror" />
</div>
<div class="line">
  <img class="active" src="../Pics/January_2019/crash4.jpg" alt="Or we're not linking up" />
  <img src="../Pics/January_2019/crash5.jpg" alt="Still checkin?" />
  <img src="../Pics/January_2019/NYbridge.jpg" alt="A bridge you can't see" />
</div>
```

Images are absent from example, but you get the idea from the alt texts showing.

Comment: I see what you did. Na, I was thinking one carousel, the images are in different divs for position purposes... I'm trynna implement some of what you gave up tho, I just think it's easier to switch the classes I have rather than add and remove classes. Not workin yet

Comment: You could add a 'working' code snippet to your question with your new implementation so it becomes more clear what the desired outcome should be.